Does the fact that electrons share the same property need an explanation?
Richard Swinburne in his book Is There A God? argues that this does, and further argues that the fact that there are trillions of particles sharing the same property is the height of unexplained complexity.
As Richard Dawkins indicates in his book review,

Science explains complex things in terms of the interactions of simpler things, ultimately the interactions of fundamental particles. I (and I dare say you) think it a beautifully simple idea that all things are made of different combinations of fundamental particles which, although exceedingly numerous, are drawn from a small, finite set. If we are sceptical, it is likely to be because we think the idea too simple. But for Swinburne it is not simple at all, quite the reverse.


His reasoning is very odd indeed.  Given that the number of particles of any one type, say electrons, is large, Swinburne thinks it too much of a coincidence for so many to have the same properties. One electron, he could stomach. But billions and billions of electrons, all with the same properties, that is what really excites his incredulity. For him it would be simpler, more natural, less demanding of explanation, if all electrons were different from each other. Worse, no one electron should naturally retain its properties for more than an instant at a time, but would be expected to change capriciously, haphazardly and fleetingly from moment to moment. That is Swinburne’s view of the simple, native state of affairs. Anything more uniform (what you or I would call more simple) requires a special explanation.

And to quote from Swinburne’s book,

It is only because electrons and bits of copper and all other material objects have the same powers in the twentieth century as they did in the nineteenth century that things are as they are now. (Is There a God? Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1996. p. 2)

Swinburne then argues that God is the best explainer for why there are fundamental particles that share properties. This begs the question: is the fact that there are particles that share the same properties and persist having the same properties a coincidence that needs further explaining, or not?
Interestingly, there is a video of these people discussing this very matter over the last year here.
From what I gather, this highlights the difference between quantitative and qualitative parsimony. As per the SEP, it seems to indicate that the philosophical literature is more biased towards the kind of simplicity Dawkins talks about rather than Swinburne. See here and the relevant quote:

Before setting aside the definitional question for ontological parsimony, one further distinction should be mentioned. This distinction is between qualitative parsimony (roughly, the number of types (or kinds) of thing postulated) and quantitative parsimony (roughly, the number of individual things postulated).[5] The default reading of Occam’s Razor in the bulk of the philosophical literature is as a principle of qualitative parsimony.

So this obviously inspires a follow up question as to why qualitative parsimony is preferred among philosophers but for now I digress.

The idea that God is the best explainer of any given thing seems exceedingly odd.  To my thinking, God is absolutely the final fallback if all and any other explanation has failed.

@Syed If politeness would not forbid, Dawkins' review might have added: One fool can ask more than seven wise men can answer.

If I have two particles that have some properties that they do not share, they are not the same particle. The up and charm quark, for instance, are completely identical except for their mass; this does not make them both an instance of the same particle with different properties, but rather two different particle species.

Electrons are all the same because they're all made of the same thing: they're all excitations of the same quantum field.

Yes, it is begging for an explanation. No, God is not the best explanation.
As for the difference between qualitative and quantitative parsimony, consider a bucket of sand and the Sahara. As far as I know, the grains of sand in each are the product of erosion. Does the fact that there are vastly more grains in one call for an entirely different explanation for how they were produced?

Good question.
One reason could be that we live in a universe with only one electron: the One-electron universe.

Feynman tells the story in one of his lectures: I received a telephone call one day at the graduate college at Princeton from Professor Wheeler, in which he said, "Feynman, I know why all electrons have the same charge and the same mass" "Why?" "Because, they are all the same electron!"

This theory is not taken seriously, but it is fun to ponder...
More seriously is the consideration that electrons are elementary particles, like electrons, quarks, and photons, and are considered point particles because they have no known internal structure, while composite particles like protons and neutrons are made up of smaller particles and therefore are not point particles. That there is a necessity that electrons share, for example, the same mass, becomes clear if you assume one electron would be heavier than another, than there would be a difference. Since they have no internal structure and are not composite, it is not conceivable where that difference could come from.
Does the fact that electrons are fundamental and have no internal structure need an explanation is maybe not answered, but I would think that it is much the same question as asking whether the speed of light needs an explanation. The mass of an electron is one of the fundamental physical constants of nature.

There are some theories that say that elementary particles have further internal structure, but we have not revealed any such structure in particle accelerators yet. We don’t have evidence for there being a substructure, but you also can’t prove a negative. (+1)
